# Add Custom Events to Collection Editor

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, design-time

I hope someone can point me in the right direction?

This is a C# .Net Winforms question, and I'm using VS2010 Express.

I've created a **List<>** collection which is embeded in a user control. I can edit the properties of the List using the Designer's **Collection Editor**. I would now like to include a **custom event** *(ItemSelected for example)* in the Collection Editor as well. This is where i'm stuck, as I've been searching google for hours now but just can't find the answer. *(It might be that i'm not using the right search phrase or something?)*

Has anyone been able to do this or is the Collection Editor strictly for properties only?

This is what i've tried, but it's just not showing up...

```
public delegate void ItemSelectedHandler(object sender);

        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]        
        public event ItemSelectedHandler ItemSelected;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh yikes that puts me down an awkward route of a 'one event for many'. Basically I've created a toolbox control. I have a toolbox container. The container contains my List<ToolboxGroup> and each ToolboxGroup contains a List<ToolboxControls>. I wanted to place an event inside ToolboxGroup for when a ToolboxControl is clicked and dragged. From what's been said, it sounds like I can only have one event that would pass the group name including the toolbox control clicked. My fear with this is that it would become very bulky and hard to manage having one event for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need the Collection Editor to edit an event, that's only for lists of things. You can find your `ItemSelected` event in the properties window by clicking the lightning bolt to display the events with your user control selected.